# Ubuntu 15.04 extremely slow

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 15.04

Last night I switched from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 15.04, I was told to use 15.04 instead of 14.04 LTS.

### **Issues**

---

1. Every time Ubuntu reaches the login screen it freezes for like 2 minutes before I can input my password.
2. I have very odd graphical glitches where half of the screen would go black and I no longer have control over the mouse.
3. Sometimes the whole sidebar and the top menu bar disappears after logging in.

### **PC Overview**

---

**Memory** 7.7 GiB

**Processor** AMD Athlon(tm) X4 860K Quad Core Processor x 4

**Graphics** Gallium 0.4 on NV44

**OS Type** 64-bit

### **What I have tried?**

---

I have tried to install and use the NVidia graphics card drivers but it seems to mess up even more, I get stuck in a login loop which I've Google'd, however it still didn't fix the issue so I removed NVidia.

I changed from *lightdm* to *gdm* (not that I know what it does) but it still didn't do anything at all.

### My Predicament

I literally have 0 knowledge on Linux, so if the answers could be in layman's terms it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Try another [desktop environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available) (compatibility issues)

If you use plasma5 (from KDE), you may have the same issue as me. But I guess you have the normal Ubuntu with *Unity* desktop. Anyway here my experience:

---

I've also switched to Ubuntu-Studio (default desktop is *XFCE*) 15.04 and installed the new KDE desktop *plasma5*. At first it went well, but then the graphics and all glitched really hard - thought it was my SSD, but now I am using *XFCE* again and it is all fine.

I **heard** that the plasma5 desktop runs fine on gentoo Linux, so **maybe there are compatibility issues between the new ubuntu version and the new plasma version**

In addition please tell us your desktop environment and/or Ubuntu distro (e.g. normal Ubuntu or Kubuntu (KDE)...).

*Another desktop can be installed with the software center/package manager and then is available at the login screen (lightdm should be fine for your login screen system)*

Comment: I'm curious, does my PC requirements not meet Ubuntu's specifications?

Comment: RAM should be more than enough. I would say min 1 GB. CPU should be fine too - for comparison: I use AMD dualcore 3200MHz

Comment: RAM should be more than enough. I would say min 1 GB. CPU should be fine too - for comparison: I use AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 260 Processor (dualcore 800 - 3200MHz). Graphics I cannot estimate, but for comparison: I use GeForce GT 640. About 2 yrs old.

Comment: For now I've installed the GNOME shell, it is performing very well, thanks. Is it 15.04 that's causing the issue? I'm wondering would 14.04 LTS perform better?